# How can I change a URL based on region and language selection?

Tags: 7, uri

I have five different regions and languages. When loading a page, the URL ends with [domain name]/[region name]/[language name]. When users change the language or the region, the URL should reflect that.

How can this be achieved?

Comment: You can change language based on such parameters on /admin/config/regional/i18n. (I am not at the position to check at the moment.)

Answer (score 0):

I've used a couple hooks in the past to rewrite all inbound/outbound URLs for Drupal 6. The Drupal 7 equivalent hooks are:

```
function mymodule_url_inbound_alter(&$path, $original_path, $path_language) {
  // Remove "region/language/" from beginning of $path
}
```

Official documentation: [hook_url_inbound_alter](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_url_inbound_alter/7)

```
function mymodule_url_outbound_alter(&$path, &$options, $original_path) {
  // Prepend $path with "region/language/"
}
```

Official documentation: [hook_url_outbound_alter](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_url_outbound_alter/7)

I don't recall the details of my implementation (it was several years ago), but this was the core of it.